# I'm new to programming and am stuggling with a simple coffee task in C#

Tags: c#

I just started doing some C# and gave myself the task of making a simple console-based coffee shop programme that just simply makes a list of what you want and then outputs it back to you when you put it all in. The only way I have found so far that has worked well for me has been to do this:

```
string Tea = "tea";
string Option1 = Console.ReadLine();

if ((Option1 == Tea)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            //Confirmation Text
            Console.WriteLine("So you want a " + Option1 + ".");

            //Second Question
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want milk, sugar, both or none?");

            //Second Option
            string Option2 = Console.ReadLine();

            //Milk
            if (string.Equals(Milk, Option2))
            {
                Console.Clear();
                //Confirmation Text
                Console.WriteLine("So you want a " + Option1 + " with " + Option2 + ".");

                //Third Question
                Console.WriteLine("And so what size will that be, small, medium, or large?");

                //Third Option
                string Option3 = Console.ReadLine();

                if (string.Equals(Large, Option3))
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    //Last Confirmation
                    Console.WriteLine("Here is your " + Option3 + " " + Option1 + " with " + Option2 + ".");
                    Console.ReadKey();

                }
                else if (string.Equals(Medium, Option3))
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    //Last Confirmation
                    Console.WriteLine("Here is your " + Option3 + " " + Option1 + " with " + Option2 + ".");
                    Console.ReadKey();

                }
                else if (string.Equals(Small, Option3))
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    //Last Confirmation
                    Console.WriteLine("Here is your " + Option3 + " " + Option1 + " with " + Option2 + ".");
                    Console.ReadKey();

                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not one of our sizes.");

            }
```

But this seems like far too much code to do a simple task as I keep having to repeat things over and over again. I have tried to look up other methods but I can't seem to grasp how you implement them into what I'm trying to do. And also implementing a loop was also a goal but I couldn't figure that out either.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the issue you have is. If you want to find a better way to represent such a scenario, you might want to look at the Decorator Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in software development if you are reusing the same code over and over again you should move that code into a method.

My following solution is far from perfect because I have had to use static methods due to accessing the methods I have wrote from the "main" class which is static itself. It would have been much better for me to have created a class to handle the logic and instantiate that class.

Considering you say you are new to programming I have avoided doing anything that might be confusing and instead tried to just reuse the code where possible just to demonstrate code reuse.

Here is my solution to your problem:

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {

    string Option1 = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Option1 == "Tea")
    {
       string[] questionSet1 = { "So you want a " + Option1 + ".", 
                                 "Do you want milk, sugar, both or none?"};

       //Confirmation Text
       string Option2 = PrintTextArray(questionSet1);

       //Milk
       if (Option2.Equals("Milk"))
       {
          string[] questionSet2 = { "So you want a " + Option1 + " with " + Option2 + ".", 
                                    "And so what size will that be, small, medium, or large?"};
          //Confirmation Text
          string Option3 = PrintTextArray(questionSet2);

          if (Option3.Equals("Large"))
          {
             //Last Confirmation
             PrintText("Here is your " + Option3 + " " + Option1 + " with " + 

Option2 + ".");

           }
           else if (Option3.Equals("Medium"))
           {
              //Last Confirmation
              PrintText("Here is your " + Option3 + " " + Option1 + " with " + Option2 + ".");

           }
           else if (Option3.Equals("Small"))
           {
              //Last Confirmation
              PrintText("Here is your " + Option3 + " " + Option1 + " with " + Option2 + ".");

           }
           else Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not one of our sizes.");

         }
      }
  }

  private static string PrintText(string textToPrint)
  {
    string[] textListToPrint = { textToPrint };

    return PrintTextArray(textListToPrint);
  }

  private static string PrintTextArray(string[] textListToPrint)
  {
      Console.Clear();

      for(int i = 0; i < textListToPrint.Length; i++)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(textListToPrint[i]);
      }

      return Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Basically I have wrote two methods, one of them being an overloaded method, which takes a string or array of strings, prints them out and returns the next key press.

I am not going to sit and pretend that this is the perfect solution because a method should only do one thing according to the Single Reponsibility Principle but, again, considering you are new to programming I was trying to avoid over complicating it. I would highly recommend studying the **SOLID Principles**.

Finally, a couple of pointers, in C# a method should be declared starting with a capital letter for it's name and variables should be declared using the **camel case** convention. Find more information on camel case [Here](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/CamelCase)

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed a lot of duplicated code for a simple program.

Here are some suggestions to clarify the intent and simplify the implementation.

#### 1. Separate your state from the application flow.

Right now, the more options you would add, the deeper your `if` conditions would become.

Try creating data types that represent your state. Here is a suggestion:

```
public enum OrderType
{
    Tea,
    Coffee
}

public class Order
{       
    /// <summary>
    /// The type of this order (either tea or coffee).
    /// </summary>
    public OrderType Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of all options for your order. (Example ["Milk", "Sugar"])
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> Options { get; } = new List<string>();
}
```

#### 2. Clarify your application flow / intent

Use methods with clear names do create your application flow. Here's an example:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var order = new Order();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, would you like tea or coffee?");
        // Read the order type from the user.
        order.Type = ReadOrderType();

        // Get the options available for that order type.
        var availableOptions = GetAvailableOptionsFor(order.Type);

        // Print the order type and the available options for that order type.
        Console.WriteLine($"{order.Type}, all right! Would you like something in it?");

        // Get the chosen options from the user.
        order.Options = ReadChosenOptions(order.Type, availableOptions);

        if (order.Options.Any())
        {
            // Print the order with options.
            Console.WriteLine($"Okay so that's a {order.Type} with {string.Join(", ", order.Options)}. See ya!");
        }
        else
        {
            // Print the order without options.
            Console.WriteLine($"Okay so that's a plain {order.Type}. Have a great day!");
        }
    }
}
```

#### 3. Create methods to read user input.

That allows you to reuse code instead of repeating it. Here's an example:

```cs
private static OrderType ReadOrderType()
{
    var orderType = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (orderType.ToUpper())
    {
        case "TEA":
            return OrderType.Tea;
        case "COFFEE":
            return OrderType.Coffee;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine($"I'll assume coffee.");
            return OrderType.Coffee;
    }
}
```

#### Full code example

Here's the full console application I wrote to help me answer.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var order = new Order();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, would you like tea or coffee?");
            // Read the order type from the user.
            order.Type = ReadOrderType();

            // Get the options available for that order type.
            var availableOptions = GetAvailableOptionsFor(order.Type);

            // Print the order type and the available options for that order type.
            Console.WriteLine($"{order.Type}, all right! Would you like something in it?");

            // Get the chosen options from the user.
            order.Options = ReadChosenOptions(order.Type, availableOptions);

            if (order.Options.Any())
            {
                // Print the order with options.
                Console.WriteLine($"Okay so that's a {order.Type} with {string.Join(", ", order.Options)}. See ya!");
            }
            else
            {
                // Print the order without options.
                Console.WriteLine($"Okay so that's a plain {order.Type}. Have a great day!");
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<string> ReadChosenOptions(OrderType orderType, List<string> availableOptions)
    {
        var options = new List<string>();
        bool areMoreOptionsDesired = ReadYesOrNo();
        if (!areMoreOptionsDesired)
        {
            // Return no options;
            return options;
        }

        while (areMoreOptionsDesired)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Here are our options: {string.Join(", ", availableOptions)}.");
            var option = ReadOption(availableOptions);
            if (option != null)
            {
                options.Add(option);
                Console.WriteLine($"So far you got a {orderType} with {string.Join(", ", options)}.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Would you like something else in it?");
            areMoreOptionsDesired = ReadYesOrNo();
        }

        return options;
    }

    private static string ReadOption(List<string> availableOptions)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (availableOptions.Contains(input, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return input;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{input} is not a valid option.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static bool ReadYesOrNo()
    {
        var desicion = Console.ReadLine();
        if (desicion.ToUpper() == "YES")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (desicion.ToUpper() == "NO")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"I'll take that as a \"no\".");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static List<string> GetAvailableOptionsFor(OrderType orderType)
    {
        switch (orderType)
        {
            default:
            case OrderType.Tea:
                return new List<string>() { "Milk", "Sugar" };
            case OrderType.Coffee:
                return new List<string>() { "Milk", "Sugar", "Cream" };
        }
    }

    private static OrderType ReadOrderType()
    {
        var orderType = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (orderType.ToUpper())
        {
            case "TEA":
                return OrderType.Tea;
            case "COFFEE":
                return OrderType.Coffee;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine($"I'll assume coffee.");
                return OrderType.Coffee;
        }
    }
}

public enum OrderType
{
    Tea,
    Coffee
}

public class Order
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The type of this order (either tea or coffee).
    /// </summary>
    public OrderType Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of all options for your order. (Example ["Milk", "Sugar"])
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> Options { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just starting out, I'd ignore Object Oriented Programming for now and focus on how to make your code not only easy to follow, but simple enough to add new drinks to your system.

The first thing I'd do is create a function that displays a list of options to be presented to the user, and doesn't allow them to leave until they've entered a valid response from that list of options.  This will allow you to focus on the "flow" of the main program and not clutter it up with repeated hard-coded menus for each part of the system.

Here is a function that receives a prompt and a string array of options:

```
static int getMenuResponse(string prompt, string[] options)
{
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        for(int i=0; i<options.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{i+1}] {options[i]}");
        }
        Console.Write("Your choice: ");
        string response = Console.ReadLine();
        int option;
        if (int.TryParse(response, out option) && option>=1 && option<=options.Length)
        {
            return (option-1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection. Please try again.");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

An example usage might be:

```
string prompt = "How are you feeling today?";
string[] feelings = new string[] { "Good", "Indifferent", "Bad" };
int response = getMenuResponse(prompt, feelings);

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("You are feeling " + feelings[response]);
```

Output:

[image]

With that in place, you can model your store as a set of menus represented by string arrays.  Here I've setup drinks, sizes, and a different set of items that can be added to each drink:

```
string[] drinks = new string[] {"Exit", "Tea", "Coffee", "Smoothie"};
string[] drinkSizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string[] teaOptions = new string[] { "Done", "Milk", "Sugar" };
string[] coffeeOptions = new string[] { "Done", "Creamer", "Sugar", "Vanilla Syrup", "Hazelnut Syrup"};
string[] smoothieOptions = new string[] { "Done", "Strawberry", "Banana", "Blueberry" };
```

We can use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) to associate each list of options with its respective drink name:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> drinkOptions = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
drinkOptions.Add("Tea", teaOptions);
drinkOptions.Add("Coffee", coffeeOptions);
drinkOptions.Add("Smoothie", smoothieOptions);
```

This will allow us to retrieve the list of items that can be added to each respective drink.

Next we'll declare some variables to track the current drink, size, and a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1) of items that have been added:

```
string size;
string drink;            
List<string> options = new List<string>();
```

With the framework for our menus setup, we'll now use [do...while](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do) loops to ask for the drink type and size.  Inside that, we'll use another inner `do...while` loop to allow as many items to be added to the drink as the user would like:

```
bool exit = false;
int option;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to The Drink Shop!");

    option = getMenuResponse("What drink would you like?", drinks);                
    exit = (option == 0);
    if (!exit)
    {
        drink = drinks[option];

        options.Clear();
        if (drinkOptions.ContainsKey(drink))
        {
            string[] curOptions = drinkOptions[drink];
            do
            {
                option = getMenuResponse("What would you like in your " + drink + "?", curOptions);
                if (option != 0)
                {
                    string itemToAdd = curOptions[option];
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    if (!options.Contains(itemToAdd))
                    {
                        options.Add(itemToAdd);
                        Console.WriteLine(itemToAdd + " added.");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(itemToAdd + " previously added.");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Current Items: " + string.Join(", ", options));
                }
            } while (option != 0);

            option = getMenuResponse("What size would you like?", drinkSizes);
            size = drinkSizes[option];

            string optionsAdded = "Nothing Added";
            if (options.Count > 0)
            {
                optionsAdded = String.Join(", ", options);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You have ordered a " + size + " " + drink + " with: " + optionsAdded);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Options missing for " + drink + "!");
        }                    
    }
} while (!exit);
```

Example of the program running:

[image]

Here is the whole program all together:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] drinks = new string[] {"Exit", "Tea", "Coffee", "Smoothie"};
        string[] drinkSizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

        string[] teaOptions = new string[] { "Done", "Milk", "Sugar" };
        string[] coffeeOptions = new string[] { "Done", "Creamer", "Sugar", "Vanilla Syrup", "Hazelnut Syrup"};
        string[] smoothieOptions = new string[] { "Done", "Strawberry", "Banana", "Blueberry" };

        Dictionary<string, string[]> drinkOptions = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
        drinkOptions.Add("Tea", teaOptions);
        drinkOptions.Add("Coffee", coffeeOptions);
        drinkOptions.Add("Smoothie", smoothieOptions);

        string size;
        string drink;            
        List<string> options = new List<string>();

        bool exit = false;
        int option;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to The Drink Shop!");

            option = getMenuResponse("What drink would you like?", drinks);                
            exit = (option == 0);
            if (!exit)
            {
                drink = drinks[option];

                options.Clear();
                if (drinkOptions.ContainsKey(drink))
                {
                    string[] curOptions = drinkOptions[drink];
                    do
                    {
                        option = getMenuResponse("What would you like in your " + drink + "?", curOptions);
                        if (option != 0)
                        {
                            string itemToAdd = curOptions[option];
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            if (!options.Contains(itemToAdd))
                            {
                                options.Add(itemToAdd);
                                Console.WriteLine(itemToAdd + " added.");
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                Console.WriteLine(itemToAdd + " previously added.");
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("Current Items: " + string.Join(", ", options));
                        }
                    } while (option != 0);

                    option = getMenuResponse("What size would you like?", drinkSizes);
                    size = drinkSizes[option];

                    string optionsAdded = "Nothing Added";
                    if (options.Count > 0)
                    {
                        optionsAdded = String.Join(", ", options);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("You have ordered a " + size + " " + drink + " with: " + optionsAdded);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Options missing for " + drink + "!");
                }                    
            }
        } while (!exit);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int getMenuResponse(string prompt, string[] options)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            for(int i=0; i<options.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{i+1}] {options[i]}");
            }
            Console.Write("Your choice: ");
            string response = Console.ReadLine();
            int option;
            if (int.TryParse(response, out option) && option>=1 && option<=options.Length)
            {
                return (option-1);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection. Please try again.");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

}
```

From the comments:

> Could you explain how the function works a bit? I get what certain
> parts do but not all of it.

Sure, I've added some comments in the code below:

```
static int getMenuResponse(string prompt, string[] options)
{
    while(true) // we keep asking for a number until we've gotten valid input
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(prompt); // display the prompt 

        // display each item from the passed in string array,
        // with "1", "2", "3", etc in front of it
        for(int i=0; i<options.Length; i++)
        {
            // the output below is using "string interpolation"
            Console.WriteLine($"[{i+1}] {options[i]}");
            // the line above could instead be written as:
            // Console.WriteLine("[" + (i+1) + "] " + options[i]);
        }

        // get a STRING response from the user
        Console.Write("Your choice: ");
        string response = Console.ReadLine();

        // attempt to convert the string into a valid integer
        // int.TryParse() returns true if successful, otherwise false
        // if successful, AND the integer is between 1 and
        // the number of choices in the string array, 
        // then return the zero based index number representing their choice
        int option;
        if (int.TryParse(response, out option) && option>=1 && option<=options.Length)
        {
            return (option-1);
        }

        // if we get here, then the user input was not a valid integer
        // and/or was outside the range of valid choices from the menu
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection. Please try again.");
        Console.WriteLine();

    } // end of the while loop - go back to the top and repeat
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I didn't think people would go this far to help

Comment: No problem.  Ask as many questions as you like if you need clarification on what anything is doing.

Comment: Could you explain how the function works a bit? I get what certain parts do but not all of it.

Comment: I added a small edit at the bottom with the function code annotated with comments.

Answer (score -2):

I'd generate an XML file, with al the information: Items available, all the posible extras, the relationship between items, the order.. maybe the cost and all the "information".
First job is to design this xml file, which depends on the kind of information you need to deal with.
Then the C# code should load that xml and give the user the options, capture the answers and so.
This way you have properly separated the information from the logic. You can then add items to the xml file.. translate it to other languages simply, without need to modify the logic part. As well as modify the logic (replace the console for some winform por example) without modifying the xml file.
A bit harder al the begining but much more powerful and manteinable on the long term.